# Unable to update rows individually

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I am trying to update our patient table within our system, but due to a connection we have with the state that sends modifications to that table to an external system I'm unable to do mass updates due to several triggers in our system (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2). The main piece of code in the trigger that is preventing

```
IF (@numrows > 1) 
BEGIN
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    SELECT @errmsg = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) + ' : more than one row is updated in table Patient'                                 
    RAISERROR(@errmsg,16,21) 
    RETURN
END
```

I cannot simply shut these triggers off where it would break a lot of things, so to do what would be a simple act of

```
update patient set security_level = '2'
where security_level = '1'
```

I used the following code which used to work in prior versions

```
declare @tmp_table table(
PRG int identity(1,1) Primary Key,
patient_id int
)

declare @start_value int = 1,
 @finish_value int,
 @patient_id int

Insert Into @tmp_table(patient_id ) Select patient_id  From patient where  security_level = '1'

Select @finish_value = max(PRG) From  @tmp_table

While @start_value <= @finish_value 
Begin
  --now get a key for patient and store in variables
  Select @patient_id =  patient_id 
  From  @tmp_table
  Where PRG = @start_value 

  --.. and now update by key
  Update patient
  set security_level = '2'
  Where patient_id  = @patient_id 


Set @start_value = @start_value  + 1
End
```

I get the following error upon running that code

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 21, Procedure tU_Patient_HL7, Line 64
>   tU_Patient_HL7 : more than one row is updated in table Patient
>
> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Any idea how I could tweak this or recode this to update the security level of all patients who have a security level set at 1 and switch it to 2?

Update
Would there be any way I could loop

```
 Update top (1) patient
 set security_level = '2' 
 where security_level = '1'
```

Until all rows are affected? That would work as well.

Comment: Wow a trigger that stops bulk changes to a table. That smells really bad.  Anyway.... Can you confirm that `patient.patient_id` is a primary key or unique constraint on it? If not that smells even worse.

Comment: Patient_id is the primary key. The reason the developer told me they had it setup this way was where it sends demographics to the state, but the java applet that sends the transactions can't send mass changes.

Comment: No suprises that a developer thinks it's a good idea. Anyway I don't understand the full story here

Answer (score 1):

With out full code ,it is hard .I am guessing your update statement is conflicting with below peice of code..

**IF (@numrows > 1)**

even though you use

```
  Update patient
  set security_level = '2'
  Where patient_id  = @patient_id
```

Your update query may affect more than one row.So my best bet would be to tweak your update query to below or change trigger if you can which is desirable

```
 Update top (1) patient
  set security_level = '2'
  Where patient_id  = @patient_id
```

Comment: It's definitely the IF (@numrows > 1) from the trigger that causes the problem, but if I alter it a lot of things will break. I could do the individual update, but I have about 200 to update, so I'm hoping there is a way I can have it update the 200, but delay the time in between each update or something, so it'll let it through.

Comment: The update top is a quicker way to do the 1 by 1 though then going in manually.

Comment: Updating two hundred rows in a loop will be pretty quick (there is no reason to sprinkle delays in - it doesn't work like that). But that `@numrows` trigger is crippling basic database functionality (bulk data changes) and you really need to consider why it's there and how you can remove it permanently. It's a bad idea and it smells like someone didn't understand triggers

Comment: The reason the developer told me they had it setup this way was where it sends demographics to the state, but the java applet that sends the transactions can't send mass changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you add to your update code a "GO 100", that should do the trick. You may need to put a delay in there as well if it updates too fast for the trigger.

```
Update top (1) patient
set security_level = '2' 
where security_level = '1'
GO 100
```

The number of executions (i.e. 100 in my example) is up to you.

Comment: We have a similar constraint on some of our client servers where we can only update some security settings one at a time. It takes longer to make these changes but for better or worse, the client does this for security reasons.